# How do I select a root file system when partitioning?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I want to install Ubuntu on the C: partition where my Windows 7 is, simply to replace the systems. I've also tried to install it on another partition (without formating it), which failed!

All I get is:

> No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

I want to install Ubuntu without formatting any of my partitions. Is that possible?

Comment: "...without formating none...", did you mean "without formatting any" or "by formatting one"?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134124/why-do-i-get-no-root-file-system-is-defined-when-i-try-install-in-one-partitio

Answer (score 4):

You need to select a root file system in the advanced partition editor, select your hard drive where you want Ubuntu and set the mount point to /.
[image]

Comment: Very important: set the partition type to EXT4, Ubuntu does not like NTFS or even FAT for the root filesystem.

Comment: Good point. Ubuntu can run on ntfs or fat drives, it's just slower. But you can access it in Windows that way.

Comment: That works only if you've a file holding the filesystem (the method used for persistent Live USB). The other method is Wubi and uses a file on the NTFS disk as well.

Comment: Yes, and it is a lot harder to do it that way too.

Comment: And that's why you're recommended to partition it as mentioned in this answer :)

Comment: Yep, pretty much.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like Wubi might be better for you... if you don't want to rearrange or format any of your partitions, you can consider using Wubi (see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) for more information about Wubi).

Normally I do not recommend Wubi, but if you absolutely do not want to change your partition structure or format any of your partitions, that might be the way to go.