# Why do I get "No root file system is defined" when I try install in one partition?

Tags: system-installation

I have 3 partitions on my computer.

```
+-----------+-------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Device   |  Type |   Size   |  Used   |                                                 Comments                                                 |
+-----------+-------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| /dev/sda1 | ntfs  | 104MB    | 35MB    | This is Windows loader                                                                                   |
| /dev/sda2 | ntfs  | 144598MB | 64536MB | Here I want to install UBUNTU                                                                            |
| /dev/sda3 | ntfs  | 105353MB | 20227MB | This my backup partition. I don't want to delete anything from here, I have all my necessary information |
+-----------+-------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is when I select "Device for boot loader installation" `/dev/sda2`.

I get:

```
No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install, "no root file system is defined" ](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94552/unable-to-install-no-root-file-system-is-defined)

Comment: Then define. Must select mount point as /. It will resolve the issue

Answer (score 99):

The complaining is that you have not defined which will be the "/" (= root partition).

Look at this image and pay attention at the "Mount Point":

[image]

Comment: Ok. But doing this I don't lose my backup partition, no?

Comment: I don't care of Windows. I want to only have Ubuntu

Comment: You don't need to select a "/boot" path but you must select "/" path . As you say in you question that should be /dev/sda2

Comment: Also the boot loader install should be /dev/sda not /dev/sda2

Comment: Do not touch /dev/sda3 that is your backup and you should be fine. But I would also make a backup in an external media "just in case"...

Comment: @desgua. Would you mind expanding on your answer? Are you saying you should put "/' as mount point? What should be the mount point if I ave (unnamed as far as I can tell) free space that I want to use for the Linux partition.

Comment: @Kvothe you have to put "/" as mount point. It is how the operating system knows where is the root directory.

Answer (score 24):

Make sure that the partition file system you wish to install Linux, Ubuntu or Backtrack on it is ext4, ext3 or ext2, and not FAT32 or NTFS.

Then mount `/` on it:

1. During the installation process press "change" on the partition you wish to use
2. Make sure "do not use this partition" scroll is not chosen, scroll to ext4, ext3 or ext2
3. On the "mount" field write `/`
4. Click ok, then next a message will appear saying something like "swap area was not defined, do you wish to continue or choose a swap area?", click "ok" and continue or click "go back" and choose another partition and click change, on the file system scroll choose "swap" and click "ok" and next

This will solve both "no root file system is defined" and the "swap area" message, if you still get the swap area message then on step 4 mount `/swap` to the partition

Comment: Newer versions of Ubuntu use a swap file instead of a swap partition.

Comment: The mount point `/` and selecting swap space helped to complete the installation successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the extension is either:

**ext2, ext3 or ext4**    but i'd recommend you select **ext4-journouling** file system. The mount point is in `/`