# How to reinstall Ubuntu but keep /home folder?

Tags: system-installation

I want to reinstall Ubuntu but keep `/home`.

I choose manual partitioning (*Something-else*  option), then select *Ubuntu system partition* and set its mount point as `/home`.

When I clicked on *Install Now*, I got the error message:

`No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu`.

What should I do to resolve this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/coqy5gohk15fg3e/DSC_0017.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Also look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/134124/why-do-i-get-no-root-file-system-is-defined-when-i-try-install-in-one-partitio

Comment: Untick format to keep your old HOME on installing  to existing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message states, you need first to define the *root* [file system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained).

So these steps should resolve the problem:

1. create an `ext4`large partition.

> ext4 is a modern iteration of ext3. Best choice for new installations where
>   super-standard isn't necessary.

2. select mounting point (`/`) and set as *primary* drive
3. create a swap partition (*logical*)