# no boot; /sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libcryptsetup.so.12: invalid ELF header

Tags: boot, 18.04

very short description: I have a dual boot (Ubuntu 18.04; Windows 10) Thinkpad and I can't boot into Ubuntu. Along with the error posted in the subject line I also get these tidbits ...

```
couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
/dev/sda6/:clean 384938/2215696 files, 4456623/8876800 blocks
Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
<<< more stuff >>>
```

Longer story: I needed more space on the ubuntu side of the dual boot. I used gparted (on a 'test ubuntu' thumbdrive) to take space from Windows and give it to the Ubuntu partitions. I had many steps in gparted. It all processed and I could boot into Unbuntu and I could see the expanded space!  The next day I tried booting into windows and Windows was not happy -- it went through various 'drive repair' steps but did "fix" whatever it felt it needed and then was able to boot into windows. Later I tried booting back into Ubuntu and it failed. This is where I'm at.

I've tried various repairs of grub (including running boot repair `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair` a few times). I have also just tried running `gparted` again and making slight changes, but alas, that didn't work either.

Here's an image of the error messages:
[stack trace and line by line error msgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgRpV.jpg)

Are there any other suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a link to your boot-repair output.  That will provide enough info for providing help.  How does it fail?  Does grub even show up?

Comment: Yes, grub show up and allows choices. If I choose ubuntu, it then stalls at these errors. Ok, I'll try to get the boot repair output!  thanks for commenting.

Comment: @ubfan1 here's a link to boot-repair info:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tyauzi1pknrm5o/Boot-Info_20191231_2341.txt?dl=0      I'm running repair again and will post its output as well.

Comment: This time Boot-repair said  there is an error during repair. I can't remember if it had said that previously. Here is output from the repair attempt. https://www.dropbox.com/s/55n3jyri9xma8lb/Boot-Info_20191231_2359.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and have attempted a reinstall while trying to keep data, following directions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

and here:

[Why do I get "No root file system is defined" when I try install in one partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134124/why-do-i-get-no-root-file-system-is-defined-when-i-try-install-in-one-partitio)

the key was being sure to set the existing partitions correctly. I had one partition set to /home, keeping it, and the other partition set to "/" and had to reformat that one during install. I needed only a few program installs in the end.